# Eclipse Luna: Remove certain projects from Navigator?

Tags: eclipse-luna

I'm wondering how/if I can remove certain projects from the navigator menu in Eclipse? I'm in uni and I have multiple projects with similar names because of how I have to name files for labs, and it gets cluttered having so many projects showing. I was wondering if there was a way to remove them from the navigator without actually deleting them, that way I could hide the ones from last semester.

Answer (score 0):

The Navigator view is old one. You can hide some predefined resources from it but not projects.

Better use Project explorer/Package explorer view.

First close the projects you want to hide in Project explorer/Package explorer view then refer this [blog](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hide-closed-projects-eclipse-project-explorer-view/) to hide them

Note that closing the projects also makes eclipse to work faster.